# writing maximum values to a dictionary without overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a bilingual dictionary ("probabilities") containing translation probabilities P(c|e). This is the probability that given a particular English word e, the translation will be a particular Chinese word c. The dictionary keys look like this: `probabilities[chinese_word + " | " + english_word]`

I also have a corpus ("bitext") of Chinese sentences aligned with their English translation. Now, for each pair of sentences, for each Chinese word i, I want to loop over all English words j and select the word(s) for which P(c_i | e_j) is highest. I do this by defining a variable argmax as 0, and updating this variable when a probability is the same or higher.

This is the problem: some c|e combinations have the exact same translation probability. However, since dictionary keys have to be unique, my code only stores the last c|e combination it has seen. I want it to be able to store several c|e combinations, if they share the highest translation probability. How do I do this?

```
alignments = {}    

for k in range(1, number_of_sent+1):

    sentences = bitext[k-1]
    chinese_sent = sentences[0]
    english_sent = sentences[1]

    for i in range(len(chinese_sent)):
        argmax = 0
        for j in range(len(english_sent)):
            if probabilities[chinese_sent[i] + " | " + english_sent[j]] >= argmax:
                argmax = probabilities[chinese_sent[i] + " | " + english_sent[j]]
                alignments[k, chinese_sent[i]] = english_sent[j]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to a store multiple values per key, your "alignments" dictionary have to store some sort of collection, like a list. For instance:

```
from collections import defaultdict

alignments = defauldict(list)

...
[the remainder of your code]
... 

alignments[k, chinese_sent[i]].append(english_sent[j])
```

---

Btw, two changes would make your code more cleaner:

1. chinese_sent and english sent are iterables and you do not need the indexes, so you do not need to use range in your loops.
2. you can use tuples instead of strings as the probabilities dictionary keys.

Your code would then become:

```
from collections import defaultdict

alignments = defauldict(list)

for k in range(1, number_of_sent+1):

    sentences = bitext[k-1]
    chinese_sent = sentences[0]
    english_sent = sentences[1]

    for cs in chinese_sent:
        argmax = 0
        for es in english_sent:
            if probabilities[cs,es] >= argmax:
                argmax = probabilities[cs,es]
                alignments[k, cs].append(es)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing a single value, try to associate the key to a list:

```
alignments[k, chinese_sent[i]].append(english_sent[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn values of your dictionary as a list instead of a single value, that is, have a dictionary of lists.

Answer (score 0):

alignments[k, chinese_sent[i]] should be a list or an array, if you see the current vaue its higer then you set it to a new list or array and store the probability and update argmax . If its the same then you add a new value to that list.